# Roku - Brightscript on eclipse is not working

Tags: eclipse, roku, brightscript

Now I'm learning Roku's `BrightScript`. I found eclipse is a good IDE for `BrightScript` development. But I'm not sure, should I register in their Roku's developer website? I have a sample code. When I used to run the code  , it is showing this

[image]

I just followed their instructions from [here](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Eclipse+Plugin+Guide).

I don't know, how to solve this problem. I don't know why this is coming. Please help me to solve this issue.Also, you can give me the right direction for `BrightScript` development. And it is more appreciable.

Here are the details.

> Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>
> Version: Juno Service Release 2
>
> Build id: 20130225-0426
>
> OS : ubuntu 14.04

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are not already a heavy user of Eclipse, installing that just for Roku would be undue pain and suffering. For more keep an eye on http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=95340

The good news is there is no secret sauce in Eclipse - you can do BrightScript development with any favorite IDE of yours that supports VB Script syntax highlighting + manual (or trivial script) packaging and upload to Roku player.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I appreciate that. But I didn't find the solution from your answer. I have sublime. But they are recommending eclipse. And this is my doubt, can I debug (to see the console)  the brightscript without connecting Roku device.?

Comment: @Yahoo - no, you cannot debug BrightScript in Eclipse, _regardless_ whether you connect Roku device or not! The plugin does not include debugger of any sorts (you know - breakpoints, step, watch variables) - it has a telnet console instead. You can do exactly the same by doing `telnet <my-roku-IP> 8085` from command line, that's the kind of debugging for Roku you can do - and a device is required for that

Comment: is there any emulator?

Comment: @Yahoo: nope, no emulators. Physical player required.

Answer (score 0):

Try following Installation Steps from [here](https://blog.roku.com/developer/2016/04/20/roku-eclipse-plugin/). Also there is a list of some useful features.